# Calendar events $filter query on start/timeZone in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'd like to apply a filter to the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/<calendar>/events` endpoint by providing the OData v4.0 `$filter` as a query parameter, but applying `eq` to `start/timeZone` results in an error:

When `$filter` is `subject eq 'My Subject' and start/dateTime eq '1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000' and end/dateTime eq '1970-01-01T00:01:00.0000000' and start/timeZone eq 'UTC' and end/timeZone eq 'UTC'` I get back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidDateTime",
    "message": "The value 'UTC' of parameter 'DateTime' is invalid.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "68f797e2-5059-4a8a-8fc6-0063e31d6498",
      "date": "2019-06-07T13:46:54"
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation references the `Prefer: outlook.timezone` header, but only indicates that it applies to the response, and says nothing about interpreting the request:

> For all GET operations that return events, you can use the Prefer:
>   outlook.timezone header to specify the time zone for the event start
>   and end times in the response.

How can I filter on the (dateTime, timeZone) combination? It would be best if I didn't have to know the timeZone of the event and could instead query based on UTC, but I don't see how to do that either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can't filter on `timeZone` and you shouldn't have too. All DateTime values are stored in UTC. They are only converted into a local time zone when you include `Prefer: outlook.timezone`

You should be able to simply use

```
subject eq '{subject}' and start/dateTime eq '{date}T{time}' and end/dateTime eq '{date}T{time}'
```

Comment: Great! I'm not seeing it documented that the request is to be interpreted in UTC. Is it, or can I submit a request to update the docs?